# How to add title?

Tags: java, android, xml, string, algorithm

I am using `TabLayout` and `ViewPager` to create tabs, and have got it to work. For some reason, the tabs' titles aren't showing.

[image: Titles not showing]
This is weird because each tab should have text on it...

Here is the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    MyPageAdapter pageAdapter;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        tabLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(45, 237, 192));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("TITLE ONE"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("TITLE TWO"));
        tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);


        List<Fragment> fragments = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
        fragments.add(Enable.newInstance());
        fragments.add(selector.newInstance());

        pageAdapter = new MyPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);
        final ViewPager pager =
                (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        pager.setAdapter(pageAdapter);

        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(pager);

        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                pager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

That is the JAVA of MainActivity. Here is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.curlybrace.ruchir.tabs.MainActivity"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustPan|adjustResize">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />


    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Again, my tabs are working effectively, but the titles of them aren't showing.

Comment: Try to change the background color of TabLayout (to a color different than ?attr/colorPrimary)... just to test... maybe, the title is also using primary color

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove your two `addTab()` calls. You are using `setupWithViewPager()`, which means that the tabs come from the `ViewPager` and the titles come from `getPageTitle()` on your `PagerAdapter`.

Comment: How do I implement `getPageTitle()` in my `PagerAdapter`?

Comment: @RuchirBaronia: Override it and return the title for the tab, given the `ViewPager` position that you are supplied as a parameter. See [this sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/DesignSupport/TabLayout) for an app that uses `TabLayout` and `ViewPager` this way.

Comment: So if I have two tabs, the first tab has a position of zero, and the second tab has a position of one? So I can just have a conditional and return a title based on that position, right?

Comment: @RuchirBaronia: Correct. Or return the value from a two-element array. Or return the value from a two-element `ArrayList`. There are lots of possibilities. :-)

Comment: Also, can I change the color of the title, right now it is white, but I want it black.

Comment: @RuchirBaronia: There is probably a style for that, but I forget the details off the top of my head.